# Paypal return url is showing file not found error in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am using Paypal sanbox integration in .net application.
Here return URL is showing file not found error.

In local system it is working fine, when i published in test server it is showing file not found error.

I am using following code for test server,

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://10.0.0.5:65/PaypalInvoice.aspx"/>
```

Please Help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Does `http://10.0.0.5:65/PaypalInvoice.aspx` actually exist?

Comment: Yes, it is existed in Test Server. Thanks.

Comment: And by exists, we mean is it accessible from any Internet connected computer?

Comment: The `http://10.0.0.5:65` is local ip on your computer, you can not use it from outside computers. Set a noram url name, or the real ip of your computer.

Comment: Other files with http://10.0.0.5:65 are working fine.   Example http://10.0.0.5:65/services.aspx .

Comment: No I can't access `http://10.0.0.5:65/services.aspx` using my browser.

Comment: In my local system following code is working fine.   <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://localhost:49366/AOTaxWeb/PaypalInvoice.aspx"/>

Comment: I am sorry, in my local system http://10.0.0.5:65/services.aspx is working, in the same way i want to access http://10.0.0.5:65/PaypalInvoice.aspx is it possible.

Comment: See my updated answer below, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the return url in `web.config` so the hidden field value can be dynamic. Add this setting in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Paypal_Return_URL" value="http://10.0.0.5:65/PaypalInvoice.aspx" />
</appSettings>
```

then make the hidden field value taken from web.config setting above:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<%= System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Paypal_Return_URL"] %>"/>
```

After you publish the application to the test server, make sure the web.config setting in the test server look like this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Paypal_Return_URL" value="http://yourtestserverdomainname.com/PaypalInvoice.aspx" />
</appSettings>
```

or this:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Paypal_Return_URL" value="http://[your test server public IP address]/PaypalInvoice.aspx" />
</appSettings>
```